# Add slider control to menu flyout in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, winui

I am trying to embed a slider control as a menu item in UWP:

[image: Context menu with trackbar]

This can be done with Windows Forms' `ToolStripControlHost` class and, on WPF, by just adding a `Slider` directly inside a `MenuItem` in the XAML.

In UWP, adding a `Slider` inside a `MenuFlyoutSubItem` does not work as the `MenuFlyoutSubItem` expects a `MenuFlyoutItemBase`.

Writting a `SliderMenuFlyoutItem` that extends `MenuFlyoutSubItem` seems like the logical approach, however I am not sure how to draw the `Slider` and handle the mouse events in this case.

Any pointers on how this can be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just put the `Slider` into the `MenuFlyoutItemBase`?

Comment: @speyck Error: Type 'MenuFlyoutItemBase' is not usable as an object element because it is not public or does not define a public parameterless constructor or a type converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use a Flyout instead of a MenuFlyout

```
 <Flyout>
     <StackPanel>
         <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item1"/>
         <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item2"/>
         <Slider Width="100" Maximum="100" Minimum="0"/>
         <MenuFlyoutSeparator />
         <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item3"/>
     </StackPanel>              
 </Flyout>
```

Comment: This worked as expected. Out of curiosity, what is the point of the MenuFlyout class if we can achieve the same results with a StackPanel?